# Remove trailing whitespace, but on lines containing characters other than just tabs?

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I'm building a bash script, and I want to remove trailing whitespace on all lines of a file EXCEPT when the line only consists of tabs.

This is how I figured out how to remove all trailing whitespace on all lines:

```
sed -i '' -e's/[[:space:]]*$//' [FILENAME HERE]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

bang `!` operator forces the sed to do the replacement on the lines which won't contain only tabs.

```
sed -i '/^\t\+$/!s/[[:space:]]*$//' file
```

OR

```
sed -i '' '/^\t\+$/!s/[[:space:]]*$//' file
```

Comment: use `[[:blank:]]` instead of `[[:space:]]` to match only the horizontal spaces.